# $X$ is a random variable, if $\Bbb E(X^2)=1$ and $\Bbb E(X)\geq a>0$, prove that $\Bbb P(X\geq\lambda a)\geq(a-\lambda a)^2$ for $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$.

Tags: probability, integration, lp-spaces

This is a problem in KaiLai Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory*.

> Given a nonnegative random variable $X$ defined on $\Omega$, if $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X)\geq a >0$, prove that $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq \lambda a)\geq (a-\lambda a)^2$$
>   for $0\leq\lambda \leq 1$.

Let $A=\{x\in \Omega:X(x)\geq \lambda a\}$, we get
$$\int_A (X-\lambda a)\geq a-\int_A\lambda a -\int_{A^c}X$$
and $$\int_A (X^2-\lambda^2 a^2)=1-\int_A\lambda^2a^2-\int_{A^c}X^2$$
I want to contrast $\int_A (X-\lambda a)$ and $\int_A (X^2-\lambda^2 a^2)$, but I don't know how to do it, could anyone gives me some hints?

Comment: Chebyshev might be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have
$$
a\le\mathbb E(X) = \int_{X\le\lambda a}X\,dP + \int_{X\ge\lambda a}X\,dP\,\le\,\lambda a + \int_{X\ge\lambda a}X\,dP.
$$
Hence,
$$
a(1-\lambda)\,\le\,\int_{X\ge\lambda a}X\,dP\,\le\,\left(\int_{X\ge\lambda a}X^2\,dP\right)^{1/2}\cdot P(X\ge\lambda a)^{1/2}\,\le\,P(X\ge\lambda a)^{1/2}.
$$
Square this and you're done.

Comment: Thank you very much!